# Does the TFS Administator have to have MSDN?

Tags: tfs, msdn, administrator

I have a TFS Administrator who does not develop or use Visual Studio.  They only use TFS through the Web UI.  Do they need to have an MSDN, all they are really doing is setting access levels.

Answer (score 0):

TFS is licensed on a Server/CAL model. Thus, you need 1 Server license for the TFS server and 1 TFS CAL (client access license) for each user that will use TFS features.

That TFS CAL covers the usage no matter how the user accesses TFS (i.e. Visual Studio, Eclipse, Web Access client, Excel, MSProject, 3rd party tool, ect, etc).

Client access licenses (CALs) aren’t required for people who just access work items – assign them “Stakeholder” access, which is free.

So in your scenario, to manage the TFS they need CALs (client access license), Visual Studio/MSDN subscription is needed.

> The two ways to acquire TFS CALs are:
>
> 1. Purchase a TFS User CAL
> 2. 1 TFS CAL (and 1 TFS Server license) is included in **each Visual
>      Studio/MSDN subscription**. Thus, anyone who has an active MSDN
>      subscription assigned to them is covered with a TFS CAL.
>
> Client access licenses (CALs) aren’t required for people who just
>   access work items – assign them “**Stakeholder**” access, which is
>   free.
>
> Extensions to TFS such as **Test Manager**, **Package Management**,
>   and **Private Pipelines** require an **additional purchase**. Some TFS
>   Extensions are included with Visual Studio Enterprise subscriptions
>   and many others are free. Paid extensions can also be purchased
>   monthly, no Visual Studio subscription is required.

More details please refer below two blogs:

- [Understand TFS Licensing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/govdev/2012/05/14/understand-tfs-licensing/)
- [Team Foundation Server 2018 Licensing](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/tfs-pricing/)